# Is 'as' used as a conjunction here? Indeed, is the sentence grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

I don't think the word 'as' is necessary in the sentence below.

As far as I know, 'as' is a conjunction, which means there must be two clauses if it can be used. However, there's no main clause in the sentence.

Is it correct? Are there any words omitted? I believe that if there are no quotation marks the sentence is acceptable.

> As Albert Einstein once said, “Anyone who has never made a mistake has
>   never tried anything new.”

Comment: See *as* in a good dictionary. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

CGEL (p 1146) classes 'as' as a preposition in

> 27 (i) *As you know, we face a difficult year.*

and I'd certainly not label this usage that of a conjunction. 'As you know' is an adjunct. It is a pragmatic marker, as incidentally is your 'As far as I know'.

'As you know' is obviously addressee-orientated, possibly used as nothing more than a 'conversational lubricator' / palliative (though it clearly has semantic content).

'As far as I know' addresses modality (it gives an indication of how confident the speaker is of the truth of the statement).

They are both totally idiomatic, often used as sentence-starters.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that dropping the "as" really changes the meaning. With "as" the speaker is agreeing with Einstein; without "as" he's merely quoting him.